How can I overwrite a global limiter for a specific API endpoint?
I’ve run into a problem with setting up rate limits for my application. The main idea is to enable a global rate limit (affecting all endpoints) but being able to disable it for certain API endpoints and enable another rate limit for them, so we can have less restrictive ones for those endpoints.
We tried creating both: a global rate limit Middleware and a API rate limit Middleware. Both Middlewares work but the API specific one doesn't overwrite the global one. (Always both are applied) How can I change that?
builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(limiterOptions =>
{
limiterOptions.OnRejected = (context, cancellationToken) =>
{
    if (context.Lease.TryGetMetadata(MetadataName.RetryAfter, out var retryAfter))
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.RetryAfter =
            ((int)retryAfter.TotalSeconds).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    }

    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests;
    GetUserEndPoint(context.HttpContext));

    return new ValueTask();
};

limiterOptions.AddPolicy(userPolicyName, context =>
{
    var username = "anonymous user";
    if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated is true)
    {
        //await context.GetTokenAsync(JwtBearerDefaults, AuthenticationScheme, "access_token");
        username = context.Request.Headers.Authorization!;
    }

    return RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(username,
        _ => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
        {
            PermitLimit = myOptions.TokenLimit2,
            Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(myOptions.Window),
        });

});



limiterOptions.GlobalLimiter = PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, IPAddress>(context =>
{
    var test = context.Request.Host;

    IPAddress? remoteIpAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

    if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(remoteIpAddress!))
    {
        return RateLimitPartition.GetSlidingWindowLimiter
        (remoteIpAddress!,
              _ => new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions
              {
                  PermitLimit = myOptions.PermitLimit,
                  //QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst,
                  //QueueLimit = myOptions.QueueLimit,
                  Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(myOptions.Window),
                  SegmentsPerWindow = myOptions.SegmentsPerWindow
              });
    }

    return RateLimitPartition.GetNoLimiter(IPAddress.Loopback);
});

I use Rate Limiting middleware in Asp.net core 7.

How about using this package: https://github.com/sa-es-ir/DotNet.RateLimit

As mentioned by the document:

A GlobalLimiter that is applied to all requests. The global limiter
will be executed first, followed by the endpoint-specific limiter, if
one exists. The GlobalLimiter creates a partition for each IPAddress

Source codes of the middleware:
internal sealed partial class RateLimitingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly Func<OnRejectedContext, CancellationToken, ValueTask>? _defaultOnRejected;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly RateLimitingMetrics _metrics;
    private readonly PartitionedRateLimiter<HttpContext>? _globalLimiter;
    private readonly PartitionedRateLimiter<HttpContext> _endpointLimiter;
    private readonly int _rejectionStatusCode;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, DefaultRateLimiterPolicy> _policyMap;
    private readonly DefaultKeyType _defaultPolicyKey = new DefaultKeyType("__defaultPolicy", new PolicyNameKey { PolicyName = "__defaultPolicyKey" });

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="RateLimitingMiddleware"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">The <see cref="RequestDelegate"/> representing the next middleware in the pipeline.</param>
    /// <param name="logger">The <see cref="ILogger"/> used for logging.</param>
    /// <param name="options">The options for the middleware.</param>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider">The service provider.</param>
    /// <param name="metrics">The rate limiting metrics.</param>
    public RateLimitingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RateLimitingMiddleware> logger, IOptions<RateLimiterOptions> options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, RateLimitingMetrics metrics)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(next);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(logger);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(serviceProvider);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(metrics);

        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
        _metrics = metrics;
        _defaultOnRejected = options.Value.OnRejected;
        _rejectionStatusCode = options.Value.RejectionStatusCode;
        _policyMap = new Dictionary<string, DefaultRateLimiterPolicy>(options.Value.PolicyMap);

        // Activate policies passed to AddPolicy<TPartitionKey, TPolicy>
        foreach (var unactivatedPolicy in options.Value.UnactivatedPolicyMap)
        {
            _policyMap.Add(unactivatedPolicy.Key, unactivatedPolicy.Value(serviceProvider));
        }

        _globalLimiter = options.Value.GlobalLimiter;
        _endpointLimiter = CreateEndpointLimiter();
    }

    // TODO - EventSource?
    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes the logic of the middleware.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="HttpContext"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> that completes when the request leaves.</returns>
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
        // If this endpoint has a DisableRateLimitingAttribute, don't apply any rate limits.
        if (endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<DisableRateLimitingAttribute>() is not null)
        {
            return _next(context);
        }
        var enableRateLimitingAttribute = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<EnableRateLimitingAttribute>();
        // If this endpoint has no EnableRateLimitingAttribute & there's no global limiter, don't apply any rate limits.
        if (enableRateLimitingAttribute is null && _globalLimiter is null)
        {
            return _next(context);
        }

        return InvokeInternal(context, enableRateLimitingAttribute);
    }

    private async Task InvokeInternal(HttpContext context, EnableRateLimitingAttribute? enableRateLimitingAttribute)
    {
        var policyName = enableRateLimitingAttribute?.PolicyName;

        // Cache the up/down counter enabled state at the start of the middleware.
        // This ensures that the state is consistent for the entire request.
        // For example, if a meter listener starts after a request is queued, when the request exits the queue
        // the requests queued counter won't go into a negative value.
        var metricsContext = _metrics.CreateContext(policyName);

        using var leaseContext = await TryAcquireAsync(context, metricsContext);

        if (leaseContext.Lease?.IsAcquired == true)
        {
            var startTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            var currentLeaseStart = metricsContext.CurrentLeasedRequestsCounterEnabled;
            try
            {

                _metrics.LeaseStart(metricsContext);
                await _next(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                _metrics.LeaseEnd(metricsContext, startTimestamp, Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _metrics.LeaseFailed(metricsContext, leaseContext.RequestRejectionReason!.Value);

            // If the request was canceled, do not call OnRejected, just return.
            if (leaseContext.RequestRejectionReason == RequestRejectionReason.RequestCanceled)
            {
                return;
            }
            var thisRequestOnRejected = _defaultOnRejected;
            RateLimiterLog.RequestRejectedLimitsExceeded(_logger);
            // OnRejected "wins" over DefaultRejectionStatusCode - we set DefaultRejectionStatusCode first,
            // then call OnRejected in case it wants to do any further modification of the status code.
            context.Response.StatusCode = _rejectionStatusCode;

            // If this request was rejected by the endpoint limiter, use its OnRejected if available.
            if (leaseContext.RequestRejectionReason == RequestRejectionReason.EndpointLimiter)
            {
                DefaultRateLimiterPolicy? policy;
                // Use custom policy OnRejected if available, else use OnRejected from the Options if available.
                policy = enableRateLimitingAttribute?.Policy;
                if (policy is not null)
                {
                    thisRequestOnRejected = policy.OnRejected;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (policyName is not null && _policyMap.TryGetValue(policyName, out policy) && policy.OnRejected is not null)
                    {
                        thisRequestOnRejected = policy.OnRejected;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (thisRequestOnRejected is not null)
            {
                // leaseContext.Lease will only be null when the request was canceled.
                await thisRequestOnRejected(new OnRejectedContext() { HttpContext = context, Lease = leaseContext.Lease! }, context.RequestAborted);
            }
        }
    }

    private async ValueTask<LeaseContext> TryAcquireAsync(HttpContext context, MetricsContext metricsContext)
    {
        var leaseContext = CombinedAcquire(context);
        if (leaseContext.Lease?.IsAcquired == true)
        {
            return leaseContext;
        }

        var waitTask = CombinedWaitAsync(context, context.RequestAborted);
        // If the task returns immediately then the request wasn't queued.
        if (waitTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return await waitTask;
        }

        var startTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        try
        {
            _metrics.QueueStart(metricsContext);
            leaseContext = await waitTask;
            return leaseContext;
        }
        finally
        {
            _metrics.QueueEnd(metricsContext, leaseContext.RequestRejectionReason, startTimestamp, Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
        }
    }

    private LeaseContext CombinedAcquire(HttpContext context)
    {
        RateLimitLease? globalLease = null;
        RateLimitLease? endpointLease = null;

        try
        {
            if (_globalLimiter is not null)
            {
                globalLease = _globalLimiter.AttemptAcquire(context);
                if (!globalLease.IsAcquired)
                {
                    return new LeaseContext() { RequestRejectionReason = RequestRejectionReason.GlobalLimiter, Lease = globalLease };
                }
            }
            endpointLease = _endpointLimiter.AttemptAcquire(context);
            if (!endpointLease.IsAcquired)
            {
                globalLease?.Dispose();
                return new LeaseContext() { RequestRejectionReason = RequestRejectionReason.EndpointLimiter, Lease = endpointLease };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            endpointLease?.Dispose();
            globalLease?.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
        return globalLease is null ? new LeaseContext() { Lease = endpointLease } : new LeaseContext() { Lease = new DefaultCombinedLease(globalLease, endpointLease) };
    }

    private async ValueTask<LeaseContext> CombinedWaitAsync(HttpContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        RateLimitLease? globalLease = null;
        RateLimitLease? endpointLease = null;

        try
        {
            if (_globalLimiter is not null)
            {
                globalLease = await _globalLimiter.AcquireAsync(context, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                if (!globalLease.IsAcquired)
                {
                    return new LeaseContext() { RequestRejectionReason = RequestRejectionReason.GlobalLimiter, Lease = globalLease };
                }
            }
            endpointLease = await _endpointLimiter.AcquireAsync(context, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            if (!endpointLease.IsAcquired)
            {
                globalLease?.Dispose();
                return new LeaseContext() { RequestRejectionReason = RequestRejectionReason.EndpointLimiter, Lease = endpointLease };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            endpointLease?.Dispose();
            globalLease?.Dispose();
            // Don't throw if the request was canceled - instead log. 
            if (ex is OperationCanceledException && context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                RateLimiterLog.RequestCanceled(_logger);
                return new LeaseContext() { RequestRejectionReason = RequestRejectionReason.RequestCanceled };
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return globalLease is null ? new LeaseContext() { Lease = endpointLease } : new LeaseContext() { Lease = new DefaultCombinedLease(globalLease, endpointLease) };
    }

    // Create the endpoint-specific PartitionedRateLimiter
    private PartitionedRateLimiter<HttpContext> CreateEndpointLimiter()
    {
        // If we have a policy for this endpoint, use its partitioner. Else use a NoLimiter.
        return PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, DefaultKeyType>(context =>
        {
            DefaultRateLimiterPolicy? policy;
            var enableRateLimitingAttribute = context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<EnableRateLimitingAttribute>();
            if (enableRateLimitingAttribute is null)
            {
                return RateLimitPartition.GetNoLimiter<DefaultKeyType>(_defaultPolicyKey);
            }
            policy = enableRateLimitingAttribute.Policy;
            if (policy is not null)
            {
                return policy.GetPartition(context);
            }
            var name = enableRateLimitingAttribute.PolicyName;
            if (name is not null)
            {
                if (_policyMap.TryGetValue(name, out policy))
                {
                    return policy.GetPartition(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"This endpoint requires a rate limiting policy with name {name}, but no such policy exists.");
                }
            }
            // Should be impossible for both name & policy to be null, but throw in that scenario just in case.
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This endpoint requested a rate limiting policy with a null name.");
            }
        }, new DefaultKeyTypeEqualityComparer());
    }

    private static partial class RateLimiterLog
    {
        [LoggerMessage(1, LogLevel.Debug, "Rate limits exceeded, rejecting this request.", EventName = "RequestRejectedLimitsExceeded")]
        internal static partial void RequestRejectedLimitsExceeded(ILogger logger);

        [LoggerMessage(2, LogLevel.Debug, "This endpoint requires a rate limiting policy with name {PolicyName}, but no such policy exists.", EventName = "WarnMissingPolicy")]
        internal static partial void WarnMissingPolicy(ILogger logger, string policyName);

        [LoggerMessage(3, LogLevel.Debug, "The request was canceled.", EventName = "RequestCanceled")]
        internal static partial void RequestCanceled(ILogger logger);
    }
}

You should register two policies and apply them to different endpoints

Thanks for your answer. but now I have another question. I debugged my application and I saw after I meet the specific limiter for an action and that was not allowed to call again, global limiter call twice for any try after that. Why?

Do you know my question?

Do you think you might know the answer to this one as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78754133/net-8-concurrency-limiter-to-different-rpc-calls
